# Cross origin issue with SSRS report

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reporting-services, cors, ssrs-2012

I am trying to implement a ssrs report into my Angular application. Here is some code:
Template:

```
<div panel-charts style="width:100%:height:100%"                         
</div>
```

Directive:

```
a.directive('panelCharts', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         $(elem).load('http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc');
    }
   }
});
```

My application root is localhost:7063.

I am getting the following:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7063' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I understand that my problem is with CORS. I have added this to my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

That did not help. But I I have a button that fires the following when I click on it:

```
<button type="button" style="width:auto;" ng-click="runReport()">
      Test
</button>
```

And this in controller:

```
$scope.runReport = function () {
 var win = window.open('http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc', '_blank');
}
```

then it works.

Any idea how to make it work without clicking on a button?

Thanks

Edit 1. 
Request:

```
Request      URL:http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
Remote Address:10.229.232.73:80
```

request header:

```
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost:7063
Referer:http://localhost:7063/Main.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#entry-longdesc)**
>
> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

You need to add `iframe` on template instead of using `.load` jQuery method, because `script` & `css` file which are going to need by `SSRS` report application would not get loaded onto page document.

```
element.append('<iframe src="http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc" width="500px" height="500px"></iframe>')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to open the report in a new window, you can just call `window.open` in your directive:

```
a.directive('panelCharts', function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      window.open('http://localhost/Reportserver?/casechart&Title=abc');
    }
  }
});
```

CORS only applies for AJAX-requests, like jQuery's `.load`, which perform the request asynchronously within the current page.

However, if you actually want to load the report via AJAX and display it within the current page, setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is the right way to go.

On a side note: For testability reasons the preferred way to access the global `window` object is through the `$window` service ([see docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)).

Comment: <setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is the right way to go. But I tried, it did not help. Or I am missing something? I actually want to load a report into some kind of a container within my page.

Comment: this code will open up specified URL content in current tab.. and which is not what OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: Did you check in the browser dev tools if the header is actually present? You can find an explanation of the setup for different servers here: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: The crucial part is the response header ([example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt4DO.png)).

Comment: Well, I am not controlling responses. It's a SSRS report server that serves a report back.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm not familiar with SSRS but i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326892/enable-cors-for-reporting-services

Comment: @ChristianZosel I tried this and it is not working.