# Is there a way to disable X-Frame options from SSRS Report Manager URL?

Tags: tomcat, iis, iframe, reporting-services

I am trying to integrate SSRS reporting manager URL into an Iframe (Using ZK framework). 
src of Iframe is 'https://localhost/Reports_MYSQL2014/Pages/Folder.aspx'

The page is getting rendered properly but clicking on some links (Upload File, security link on folder) getting error message as

"Refused to display 'https://localhost/Reports_MYSQL2014/Pages/Import.aspx?ItemPath=%2f&&Redi.........................................' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SameOrigin'."

How can i disable the 'X-Frame-Options' from SSRS response headers?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the mgmt portal is designed/extensible enough to be embedded.

Use the SSRS v2.0 REST API and create your own list of the reports, folders, etc. inside "Pages/Folder.aspx" to render to the user however you see fit.

Explore it here: https://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0

Sample usage of REST API to get SSSR items for display on a custom UI: https://kpitsimpl.blogspot.com/2020/01/ssrs-rest-api-v2.html

Comment: I am sorry I could not help. Perhaps this might work for your situation/requirement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326892/enable-cors-for-reporting-services/62031871#62031871