# Power BI Report Server Embedding & Silent Authentication

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to silently authenticate the embeded report like done in Power BI Service. However in **Report Server** embedding is available through iframe and user is prompted to login with Windows/NTLM account. How can I authenticate silently like done in cloud based approach with a master user ?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I solved this issue for anyone wondering.

I wrote a reverse **proxy** to Power BI Reporting Server in my .Net Core application and authenticated each request with BASIC. I needed to enable **BASIC** authentication and **CORS** from application URL. (also you may need to add Network Service as content manager/viewer to your report)

Here are some useful links:

- [Proxy](https://github.com/twitchax/AspNetCore.Proxy)
- [PBIRS CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62031871/16372045)